# Components with 'Variants' in React - Conditional Rendering

Tags: reactjs, rendering

pretty basic question here.

I am trying to begin learning React and I am curious about the best design pattern to go about this sort of thing.

I have a button component, and I want a 'primary' and 'secondary' variant of the component that apply a different class. Would the following be the best way to go about that? I am passing a 'variant' prop that defines which button to use.

If this isn't the best solution, what would be if I would like 'variants' for particular components.

Thanks!

```
class Button extends Component {

render() {

  // --- SECONDARY BUTTON --- //
  if(this.props.variant == 'secondary') {

    return (
      <div className = 'button-wrapper secondary'>
        <div className = 'button'>
          {this.props.text}
        </div>
      </div>
    );

  // --- PRIMARY BUTTON --- //
  }else if(this.props.variant == 'primary') {

    return (
      <div className = 'button-wrapper primary'>
        <div className = 'button'>
          {this.props.text}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
}
```

Comment: <div className = {`button-wrapper ${ variant === 'secondary' ? '' : 'primary' }`}>

Answer (score 2):

if your difference is only in the `className`, perhaps you can achieve the same by:

```
render() {
 const { variant } = this.props;
 return (
   <div className = {`button-wrapper ${ variant === 'secondary' ? '' : 'primary' }`}>
     <div className = 'button'>
       {this.props.text}
     </div>
   </div>
 );
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be ``<div className = {`button-wrapper ${variant}`}>``?

Comment: @ArslanTariq the original post was setting empty classname for the secondary variant. You're right, if variant is exactly what the author wants to use for classname.

Comment: @JeeMok I have a same kind of question for you but this will be with the components inside it, so i have a `Component A` returns be back `Components B, C` but in the probability structure i.e `B-B || B-C || C-C || C-B` what will be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using some npm packages for these kinds of things, as they will vary from component to component, and you will end up putting many ugly if-else statements in your component. You may get it clean by creating a hook that accepts props and returns the final set of classes, but that again will be an ugly hook.

You should give a try to npm pkg `@vtechguys/vs`.

```
import { GetVariantProps, vs } from "@vtechguys/vs";
 
export const button = vs({
  // Example with Tailwind rich classes
  base: ["font-semibold", "border", "rounded"],
  variants: {
    intent: {
      color: [
        "bg-blue-500",
        "text-white",
        "border-transparent",
        "hover:bg-blue-600"
      ],
    secondary: [
        "bg-white",
        "text-gray-800",
        "border-gray-400",
        "hover:bg-gray-100"
      ]
    },
    size: {
      small: ["text-sm", "py-1", "px-2"],
      medium: ["text-base", "py-2", "px-4"]
    }
  },
  defaultVariants: {
    intent: "primary",
    size: "medium"
  }
});
 
export type ButtonVariantProps = GetVariantProps<typeof button>;
```

Not it can be simply used as

```
import React from "react";
 
type ButtonOwnProps = {
    // ... some button props ...
};
 
type ButtonProps = React.PropsWithChildren<ButtonVariantProps & ButtonOwnProps>;
 
 
export function ButtonTailwind(props: ButtonProps) {
  const { color, size, children, ...rest } = props;

  // you can event extract it in a hook to make it more clean
  const variants = button({ color, size });
  // Applicable Tailwind classes
  const classes = clsx(variants);
 
  return (
    <button className={classes} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
}
```